# Select all checkboxes in Symfony form view

Tags: php, symfony

In symfony form I have some choices, checkboxes.

```
$form->add('keywords', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => $keywords,
            'label' => 'With following keywords',
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
        ));
```

I need all checboxes **selected** when form is **initialised**. 
How I can do that if possible in symfony way or I will need to do that with JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `choice_attr`

```
$form->add('keywords', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => $keywords,
            'label' => 'With following keywords',
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
            'choice_attr' => function() {
                return ['checked' => 'checked'];
            },
        ));
```

Comment: Medard, Thanks a lot  bro :)

Comment: if you're always going to return the same array, you don't need a function for that, just use 'choice_attr' => array('checked => 'checked');

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr

Comment: Older comment - specs may have changed since 2016 but to clarify; As of Symfony 3.4 - 6.0 the callback is executed on each of the defined `choices` options. Causing `checked` to be applied to all `choices` regardless of the initial Form data state. For instance when `$builder->get('keywords')->getData() = []`. While `'choice_attr' => ['checked => 'checked']` executes only on the specified index of the defined `choices`, for example 
 `'choices' => ['choice_1' => 1]` and `'choice_attr' => ['choice_1' => ['checked' => 'checked']]`.